# I accepted an answer to my question - does that mean I should upvote it, too?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

A while ago, [I asked a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145773/why-does-my-grub-have-two-entries-for-windows#comment194430_145773) about something. An answer was provided by another user, and although it did help with my original problem, it created new problems that were discussed in comments. After a while, I ended up reinstalling the troubling software instead of trying to fix the installation (as mentioned in the comments to the answer).

I accepted the answer nonetheless, since it actually did help me with the problem I had to start with, and since I couldn't verify that the new problems were directly caused by the suggestions in the answer. Now, a month later, the user who authored the answer commented on my question, hinting that *"an upvote for the answer you accepted would be appreciated :)"*

Is this customary on askubuntu.com? The answer was awarded 15 rep since I accepted it - but does that mean that I should, by default, give it another 10 by upvoting it?

That is not how I have understood the voting customs on other SX sites, but since each site has its own community I guess things can be different on different sites. Personally, I think upvotes and accepting answers are two different things, and one should not necessarily imply the other.

Comment: I also got the same comment from the same user, and I just upvoted and moved on.

Comment: I upvote for helpful and useful answers only.

Comment: Hovering the mouse over the upvote icon gives the tool tip "This answer is useful". If the answer given was not useful, then you wouldn't have accepted it, so on that basis, then you should always upvote an answer when you accept it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, no need for that. But...

Up vote great content and correct information that helps directly solve issues on the site. Was there effort? Get that guy some rep! Was it sloppy, confusing and all in all a not so good post? Well, its up to you.

Bad content, wrong information, you don't agree with the posted information or the information is dangerous? Down vote, do nothing, again, its up to you.

**The key point is: the more voting, the merrier.**

Asking for votes? Well, not the best you can do with your time on the site, accepting an answer and not up voting it is normal and I don't consider it rude. Neither asking for an up vote, is. *No need to make a fuzz about it I think.*

If you don't agree with it you can flag it as chatty, if the same user keeps asking for more on the same post or any other posts, constantly, then probably the mods will send him/her a courtesy PM and we all move on with our lives.