# What Super-powers does a Moderator have?

Tags: support, privileges, moderators

Just out of curiosity, what powers does a moderator have?

Before I asked this question, I think of moderators as people who have super powers – who can change this site to whatever they want, like changing the rep of a user.

Comment: Up in the sky, look: It's a bird. It's a plane. It's a moderator!

Comment: Mods have super cow powers. Live with it.

Comment: We can do a lot of... stuff :s

Comment: They have what you can't imagine. They can delete you instantly.

Comment: I think it would be good to know that this question was inspired by BrunoPereira's comment on [this Question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3656/i-accepted-an-answer-to-my-question-does-that-mean-i-should-upvote-it-too)(which got removed) saying that he can strip away rep from a user until he learns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are<s>n't</s> super heroes, <s>although</s> and we <s>might</s> look like it.

We have the powers and tools mentioned in [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role), plus I have power of detecting where there is food. Although there might be *twitch* other *twitch* causes for that. ;)

Comment: I also have that extra power, weird!

Comment: Good one @jrg.  What is your super power?

Comment: And where *is* the food, anyways?